# Time efficient cut on sorted column?

Tags: python, pandas, cut

I have a set of time intervals and a time series.
I would like to process groups in this time series based on these intervals.

I have seen [`pd.IntervalIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.html) along with [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) can help me do that.
Most notably, the example given at the bottom of the documentation page for `pd.cut` is quite close to what I need.

```py
bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5)])
pd.cut([0, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 4.5], bins)
[NaN, (0.0, 1.0], NaN, (2.0, 3.0], (4.0, 5.0]]
Categories (3, interval[int64]): [(0, 1] < (2, 3] < (4, 5]]
```

But:

- my intervals are not overlapping
- my intervals are sorted
- timestamps in time series are sorted

Given these 3 conditions, I wonder if there is no function based on these conditions that would be faster.

- The time series needs only to be explored once.
- Once an interval is met, it will not be met again later on and the next one is then the one to expect next in the time series.

I thank you in advance for your advices.
Bests,

Comment: Does your intervals non continuous like in the `pd.cut` example, if they are continous, that is ex: `bins=[0,1,2,3,4,5]` then you can use `np.searchsorted`

Comment: Hi, intevals are not continuous. Why np.searchsort would not help here?